# Is there a way to view the most visited questions on an SE site?

Tags: support, questions, views, question-lists

I'm looking for a way to view the most visited questions, is there any? Obviously it differs from "questions with the most votes".

Comment: Possibly `/questions/greatest-hits`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `views:nnn` search option to narrow down the list of results to something where you can manually filter out the question with the most views. Start with a search like `views:10000` to find all questions with more than 10000 views and increase that number until you get to something like 10 results. Out of that list you can easily see which one has the most views.

E.g. after a few tries I got the following query for Meta.SO:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A50000

Which shows you that the Jon Skeet facts are the most viewed question here.

Answer (score 5):

One of the options you have is the `/questions/greatest-hits` URL, which can be used on any Stack Exchange site.  This is Stack Overflow's:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

As [mentioned by Jeff in the blog post announcing the feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/):

> The [Greatest Hits page] divides the number of page views on a
> question by the total amount of anonymous question and answer feedback
> received (adding a bonus for high view counts). We exclude questions
> with less views than the median view count for the entire site.

Granted, this means you won't get the ones with the *most* views, but questions with absurdly high views are going to float to the top of that.

Another option, if you're willing to deal with older data, is to use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to look at the `ViewCount` field on the `Posts` table.

As a matter of fact, there's a query that gets the top 100 (even though it returns 500 results) questions by views that exists already and you can use as a basis for your search:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62546/top-100-most-viewed-questions

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I liked @Fabian's answer better, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Gigili Even if I did, I couldn't do something about it, accepted answers are purely the purview of the person asking.  No worries.